# How to validate password hash using a custom sh1 encryption and a custom salt in Yii 2.0?

Tags: php, passwords, yii2, sha, password-hash

Below is my account credentials.

```
id    username      password                          salt      status
1     test          qepoihadfnkdsgbkajb1358139jbdf    35asf24s  1
```

Below is my sql query what I would like to execute.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username AND password = 'SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(':password')))))' AND status = :status";
```

Below is my code snippet to retrieve the user record.

```
$this->_user = User::findBySql($sql, [
            ':username' => $this->username,
            ':password' => $this->password,
            ':status'   => 1,
        ])->one();
```

The above code returns null. It seems like it cannot encrypt the entered password to compare with the password hash. Thus, I have tried the following code.

```
 $this->_user = User::find()->where("username = :username AND (password = 'SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(':password')))))' OR password = '" . md5(":password") . "') AND status = :status")
                                          ->addParams([
            ':username' => $this->username,
            ':password' => $this->password,
            ':status'   => 1,
        ])->one();
```

This also returns null as result. How can I encrypt the entered password using custom salt to compare with the password hash and return the record?  Even I am working with Yii 2 but I do not want to use Yii manner to log the user in because of some technical requirements.

Comment: `SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(':password'))))` move this to php variable. By the way `yii2` has own password hashing based on php. If it's fresh table maybe consider using it? And 1 more thing - encrypting few times won't make encryption level stronger, actually it will lower it and make way easier to brake.

Comment: SHA1 is a hash function, not an encryption function. https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `findBySql` if you don't have specific reason. You loose abstractions.

`'" . md5(":password") . "'` is also bad and wrong: you hashed not sql request, but string `:password`.

Look this code:

```
$query = User::find()->where('password_hash = SHA1(:password)', [
    ':password' => 'password'
]);

$sql = $query->createCommand()->getRawSql();
$user = $query->one();
```

Use `getRawSql` for debug your request. You always can see what sended to sql server.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way to check a password. It is not possible to verify a password inside an SQL statement, because of the salt which is hopefully applied. Also it is unsecure to use SHA-1 to store passwords, because this algorithm is ways too fast and can be brute-forced easily.

Instead you can do a query with only the username. If a row could be found, you can read and verify the password hash:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username AND status = :status";
```

The Yii framework offers helper functions to generate and verify password hashes. This [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-passwords.html) may get you started. An alternative is to call the PHP functions [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) directly.